# Function problem Show that function $f(x) =\frac{x^2+2x+c}{x^2+4x+3c}$ attains any real value if $0 < c \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, functions

Problem :

Show that function $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2+2x+c}{x^2+4x+3c}$ attains any real value if $0 < c \leq 1$

My approach :

Let the given function $f(x) =\dfrac{x^2+2x+c}{x^2+4x+3c} = t $   where $t$ is any arbitrary constant.

$\Rightarrow (t-1)x^2+2(2t-1)x+c(3t-1)=0$

The argument $x$ must be real, therefore $(2t-1)^2-(t-1)(3tc-c) \geq 0$.

Now how to proceed further? Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: Just continue the same way Develop your equation in "t";it is again quadratic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(2t-1)^2-(t-1)(3tc-c) \geq 0\implies 4t^2+1-4t-(3t^2c-4tc+c)\geq 0\implies t^2(4-3c)+4(c-1)t+(1-c)\geq 0$

Now a quadratic polynomial $\geq 0$ $\forall t\in \Bbb R$  iff coefficient of second power of variable is positive and Discriminant $\leq 0$

which gives $4-3c>0\implies c<\frac{4}{3}$ and $D=16(c-1)^2+4(4-3c)(c-1)\leq 0\implies 4(c-1)(4c-4+4-3c)\leq 0\implies 4(c-1)c\leq 0\implies 0\leq c\leq 1$

So $c<\frac{4}{3}$ and $0\leq c\leq 1\implies 0\leq c\leq 1$

Comment: "Now a quadratic polynomial ≥0 ∀t∈R iff coefficient of second power of variable is positive and Discriminant ≤0". Why must the discriminant be less than or equal to 0?

Comment: @coolcheetah If the discriminant is strictly positive, the quadratic polynomial has two distinct real zeros, and then it attains strictly positive as well as strictly negative values. The discriminant being $\leqslant 0$ means the polynomial never changes sign, and the coefficient of the quadratic term tells you whether the values are $\geqslant 0$ or $\leqslant 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Sorry for my ignorance, but does $\leqslant$ imply $\le$?

Comment: @coolcheetah Those are the same, $\leqslant$ just looks better than $\leq$.

Answer (score 3):

1) The numerator and the denominator cannot be both zero;

2) The denominator has a zero for some $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$;

3) $\lim_{x\to\xi^\pm}f(x)=\pm\infty$;

4) $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x)=1$;

5) By continuity, $f(x)$ attains all values in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$;

6) in $x=-\frac{1}{2}$, $f(x)=1$.

Comment: In order to prove point 2), just note that by posing $g(x)=x^2+4x+3c$ we have $g(-3)\leq 0$ and $g(1)>0$, so, by continuity, $g(x)$ has a root in the interval $[-3,0)$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that from your quadratic equation in $x$:
$$
(t-1)x^2 + (4t-2)x^2 + (3tc-c) = 0
$$
its discriminant is:
$$
\Delta_x = (4t-2)^2-4(t-1)(3tc-c)=(-12c+16)t^2+(16 c-16)t+(-4c+4)
$$
Note that it suffices to show that $\Delta_x$ is always nonnegative. To do this, we consider its discriminant with respect to $t$:
$$
\Delta_t = (16c-16)^2-4(-12c+16)(-4c+4) = 64c(c-1)
$$
Now consider what happens when $0<c\le 1$. Observe that $\Delta_t\le0$, so the parabola $(-12c+16)t^2+(16 c-16)t+(-4c+4)$ either lies completely on one side of the $t$-axis or just barely touches the $t$-axis. But since $c\le1 \implies -12c+16\ge4$, we know that the parabola must be opening upwards so that $\Delta_x \ge 0$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

To continue your approach.

Rewrite $(2t−1)^2−(t−1)(3tc−c)$ as

$(4+3c)t^2+(-4+c+3c)t+(1-c)$

This is a quadratic polynomial in $t$ with discriminant

$(-4+4c)^2-4(1-c)(4+3c)$. You want to know that this is negative for all $c$ in the given interval. You probably know how to do this. Find the zeros of this polynomial and check the interval $(0,1)$ is inside where this polynomial is negative.

Comment: "You want to know that this is negative for all c in the given interval." Could you please tell me why the discriminant of the discriminant is positive?